# ip-rule doesn't work with ToS greater than 0x10

Tags: linux, networking, ip, iproute

There is some weird behavior of [*`ip-rule`*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html) with specific IP [ToS](https://www.tucny.com/home/dscp-tos)-values. It works fine just with values up to 0x10, but doesn't accept DSCP-part.

I tried:

```
ip ru a tos 0x20 table 1234
```

And got:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TOS` was defined in RFC [791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) and further in RFC 1349 with only 4 possible bits as [seen in RFC 1349's chapter 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1349#section-3):

> ```
>             0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
>          +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
>          |                 |                       |     |
>          |   PRECEDENCE    |          TOS          | MBZ |
>          |                 |                       |     |
>          +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
> ```

and 4:

> ```
>                 1000   --   minimize delay
>                 0100   --   maximize throughput
>                 0010   --   maximize reliability
>                 0001   --   minimize monetary cost
>                 0000   --   normal service
> ```

As the MBZ (must be zero) bit is reserved and precedence was ([allegedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service#Precedence_and_ToS)?) never really used, there are only even values between 0x00 and 0x1E possible. Linux [defines this in ip.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/include/uapi/linux/ip.h#L23):

> ```
> #define IPTOS_TOS_MASK        0x1E
> #define IPTOS_TOS(tos)        ((tos)&IPTOS_TOS_MASK)
> #define   IPTOS_LOWDELAY      0x10
> #define   IPTOS_THROUGHPUT    0x08
> #define   IPTOS_RELIABILITY   0x04
> #define   IPTOS_MINCOST       0x02
> ```

and `ip rule` ('s kernel part) is just following those definitions to tell what is allowed.

Now if you want instead to use `DSCP` defined in RFCs [2474](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2474) to be an alternate mechanism replacing the `TOS` view of the same byte (along with `ECN` in RFC [3168](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3168)), there doesn't appear to exist a *direct* equivalent using `ip rule`.

What you can still do instead, is use [iptables](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#dscp) or [nftables](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8.en.html#IPV4_HEADER_EXPRESSION) to match the `dscp` field value then [ma](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#MARK)[rk](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Setting_packet_metainformation) the packet and reuse it with `fwmark` in `ip rule`.